# cocoa / Objective-C: Cross- Class Variables

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, class

Hey i was searching for a solution for my problem and i nearly have it just one tiny bit...

I have a NSView subclass (AppView) and a NSObject subclass (AppController)
In AppView i declare a boolean with the @property than i use @synthesize and than in AppController i want to access it: i found this:

(in the implementation)

```
AppView *obj;
obj.booleanDraw = YES;
```

but i have to set obj = something ... but i have no idea what. since i just want to change the boolean from the view on a button click and the button action is defined in the AppController
thanks for any help^^

Comment: What do you mean by “Cross- Class Variables”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically:

```
AppView *obj = [[AppView alloc] init];
```

But, possibly not in your case - I'd probably need to see more of your implementation to really give you a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Mr-sk is right. But if this is the sort of problem you're having, I'd suggest checking this out: http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/. That's what got me started, and I think you'd feel really good if you read it too.

Comment: Good call - Yeah Samuel you might want to dig into some basics so your able to really grasp the concepts before you move to more difficult programming - none the less, good luck going forward. 

That's a good link, I've gone through it was well in the past.

Comment: Okay thank you, well coming from the pretty straightforward PHP i have my difficulties with objective c.